# Is it wise to use a VPS as a Mail, Name, and Web Server

Tags: webserver, vps, mail-server, nameserver

I've just bought a VPS from 6sync, and initially I was planning to use it as just a mail server for my business.

However, while planning what I wanted it to do, I realised I could also do with a nameserver and a web server. The ability to have a web server is something I definately need as my current provider is proving too expensive, while having a nameserver is just really to look a bit more professional and have everything under one domain name.

My question is would it be wise for me to load the VPS to do all three jobs, or should I say buy another VPS to just act as my web server, while the other VPS could run my mail and name servers?

Currently the VPS I have has 1 CPU, 256MB RAM, and 12GB storage, but I am intending to increase this once I have finished testing it.

**EDIT:**
Just a bit more information about the sites being ran:

Most of the clients I have run Wordpress websites, so I will need MySQL server on there also. My biggest customer gets about 25/30 visits per day, while my smallest customer gets about 2/3 every other day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having all nameservers on the same box (VPS or not) and even on the same subnet isn't recommended. Some kind of backup DNS service could help.

As for the website -- your question is too general without knowing the specifics.  It really depends on the load, number of visitors, whether the site is static or dynamic. For lightweight websites, that VPS may be enough. If you use things like MySQL, you could run this on a different server or VPS. Again, the VPS that you have may or may not be enough, depends on the site you run.

It also depends on whether your VPS provider oversells a lot or not. You may find yourself with slow responding VPS depending on that. Some visualization technologies provide more separation of VPS instances than others.

Comment: Just updated my answer with more information. How could I tell if my provider oversells or not?

Comment: Overselling by itself is not an issue, but could become one not done wisely or if another customer utilizes a lot of resources. I think that KVM that 6sync uses has good separation and possibly doesn't allow overselling (but you may want to ask around about this at the forums linked below). Another thing that I've seen people recommend is to optimize the VPS (check WHT linked below) and WordPress (I assume that there should be tutorials for that). Some forums for VPS: http://www.webhostingtalk.com/forumdisplay.php?f=103 and http://lowendtalk.com (although your VPS is not exactly low end).

Answer (score 0):

The benefit of most VPS providers is that they are very flexible, so it's pretty easy to add capacity to your account as you need it. Go with running it all on one host for the time being - you can always buy new capacity in future, if you need it, either by expanding the current VPS or by purchasing a new one.

I currently run smtp, imap, clamav, web and database services on a single VPS from [ElasticHosts](http://www.elastichosts.com) - it's a little higher spec than yours, but it copes just fine.